# Counting DISTINCT over multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, query-optimization

Is there a better way of doing a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DocumentId, DocumentSessionId
      FROM DocumentOutputItems) AS internalQuery
```

I need to count the number of distinct items from this table but the distinct is over two columns.

My query works fine but I was wondering if I can get the final result using just one query (without using a sub-query)

Comment: FYI: https://community.oracle.com/ideas/18664

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75068192/8614314

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you are trying to improve performance, you could try creating a persisted computed column on either a hash or concatenated value of the two columns.

Once it is persisted,  provided the column is deterministic and you are using "sane" database settings, it can be indexed and / or statistics can be created on it.

I believe a distinct count of the computed column would be equivalent to your query.

Comment: Would you please add an example or code sample to show more about what this means and how to do it?

Comment: How is it different from creating a multi-column index on those columns? I'm sorry if this makes no sense. I'm new to SQL.

Comment: How does this trick care about hash collisions? I think the distinct counts on hash values would be smaller than the truth due to the collisions.

Answer (score 66):

**Edit: Altered from the less-than-reliable checksum-only query**
I've discovered a way to do this (in SQL Server 2005) that works pretty well for me and I can use as many columns as I need (by adding them to the CHECKSUM() function).  The REVERSE() function turns the ints into varchars to make the distinct more reliable

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CHECKSUM(DocumentId,DocumentSessionId)) + CHECKSUM(REVERSE(DocumentId),REVERSE(DocumentSessionId)) )
FROM DocumentOutPutItems
```

Comment: With hashes like Checksum(), there is small chance that the same hash will be returned for different inputs so the count may be very slightly off.  HashBytes() is an even smaller chance but still not zero.  If those two Ids were int's (32b) then a "lossless hash" could combine them into an bigint (64b) like Id1 << 32 + Id2.

Comment: the chance is not so small even, especially when you start combining columns (which is what it was supposed to be meant for). I was curious about this approach and in a particular case the checksum ended up with a count 10% smaller.  If you think of it a bit longer, Checksum just returns an int, so if you'd checksum a full bigint range you'll end up with a distinct count about 2 billion times smaller than there actually is. -1

Comment: Updated the query to include the use of "REVERSE" to remove the chance of duplicates

Comment: Could we avoid CHECKSUM -- could we just concatenate the two values together? I suppose that risks considering as the same thing: ('he', 'art') == 'hear', 't'). But I think that can be solved with a delimiter as @APC proposes (some value that doesn't appear in either column), so 'he|art' != 'hear|t' Are there other problems with a simple "concatenation" approach?

Comment: I think concatentation can work - the db still has to determine uniqueness

Comment: Do not use CHECKSUM for this. It's simply left-shift-by-4 then xor, which is the worst hash I have seen (CRC-32 would be far superior; even CRC-16 might be better!) It is very easy to construct colliding values; for example, the following are both 0:

select checksum('1234123412341234')
select checksum('abcdabcdabcdabcd')

The only valid use I can imagine for CHECKSUM is the recommended one;  when you want a small index over large text values, and you add a comparison of those text values to the where clause, to eliminate collisions.

HASHBytes may be adequate, though possibly slow.

Comment: i used with a table that has only 169 rows and it was wrong, the values "2, 550" and "3, 550" have the same result, don't use CHECKSUM, using a loop to have the values 1 to 10 in 2 columns with cross join, it should have 100 unique values but it shows 86

Answer (score 59):

To run as a single query, concatenate the columns, then get the distinct count of instances of the concatenated string.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT concat(DocumentId, DocumentSessionId)) FROM DocumentOutputItems;
```

In MySQL you can do the same thing without the concatenation step as follows:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT DocumentId, DocumentSessionId) FROM DocumentOutputItems;
```

This feature is mentioned in the MySQL documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct

Comment: This was a SQL Server question, and both options you posted have already been mentioned in the following answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1471444/4955425 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1471713/4955425.

Comment: FWIW, this almost works in PostgreSQL; just need extra parentheses: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (DocumentId, DocumentSessionId)) FROM DocumentOutputItems;`

Comment: Be very careful with this method as it could lead to incorrect counts.

The following example will return a count of 1.

    DocumentID    |    DocumentSessionID
    "A"                 |  "AB"
    "AA"               |  "B"

Comment: As @Bort notes, the first option can lead to incorrect results, and would be better written using CONCAT_WS. The 2nd method also isn't guaranteed to produce the same results as the original query, in case any of the columns are nullable.

Comment: Just throwing my two cents in - this did give me the wrong count results. I ended up just using a subquery instead. Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 49):

What is it about your existing query that you don't like?  If you are concerned that `DISTINCT` across two columns does not return just the unique permutations why not try it?

It certainly works as you might expect in Oracle.

```
SQL> select distinct deptno, job from emp
  2  order by deptno, job
  3  /

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        10 CLERK
        10 MANAGER
        10 PRESIDENT
        20 ANALYST
        20 CLERK
        20 MANAGER
        30 CLERK
        30 MANAGER
        30 SALESMAN

9 rows selected.


SQL> select count(*) from (
  2  select distinct deptno, job from emp
  3  )
  4  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         9

SQL>
```

**edit**

I went down a blind alley with analytics but the answer was depressingly obvious...

```
SQL> select count(distinct concat(deptno,job)) from emp
  2  /

COUNT(DISTINCTCONCAT(DEPTNO,JOB))
---------------------------------
                                9

SQL>
```

**edit 2**

Given the following data the concatenating solution provided above will miscount:

```
col1  col2
----  ----
A     AA
AA    A
```

So we to include a separator...

```
select col1 + '*' + col2 from t23
/
```

Obviously the chosen separator must be a character, or set of characters, which can never appear in either column.

Answer (score 24):

Some SQL databases can work with a tuple expression so you can just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (DocumentId, DocumentSessionId))
      FROM DocumentOutputItems;
```

If your database doesn't support this, it can be simulated as per @oncel-umut-turer's suggestion of CHECKSUM or other scalar function providing good uniqueness e.g.
`COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(DocumentId, ':', DocumentSessionId))`.

[MySQL specifically supports `COUNT(DISTINCT expr, expr, ...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count) which is non-SQL standard syntax. It also notes `In standard SQL, you would have to do a concatenation of all expressions inside COUNT(DISTINCT ...).`

A related use of tuples is performing `IN` queries such as:

```
SELECT * FROM DocumentOutputItems
WHERE (DocumentId, DocumentSessionId) in (('a', '1'), ('b', '2'));
```

Comment: Won't work in ORACLE, for instance

Answer (score 22):

How about something like:

```
select count(*)
from
  (select count(*) cnt
   from DocumentOutputItems
   group by DocumentId, DocumentSessionId) t1
```

Probably just does the same as you are already though but it avoids the DISTINCT.

Comment: in my tests (using SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON), it had the same execution plan and exact same TotalSubtreeCost

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the original query, solving this with `GROUP BY` may introduce a couple of additional challenges to the query transformation to achieve the desired output (e.g. when the original query already had `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clauses...)

Answer (score 15):

Here's a shorter version without the subselect:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DocumentId, DocumentSessionId) FROM DocumentOutputItems
```

It works fine in MySQL, and I think that the optimizer has an easier time understanding this one.

Edit: Apparently I misread MSSQL and MySQL - sorry about that, but maybe it helps anyway.

Comment: in SQL Server you get: __Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ','.__

Comment: @Kamil Nowicki, in SQL Server, you can only have one field in a COUNT(), in my answer I show that you can concatenate the two fields into one and try this approach.  However, I'd just stick with the original since the query plans would end up the same.

Comment: Please give a look in @JayTee answer. It works like a charm. `count ( distinct CHECKSUM ([Field1], [Field2])`

Comment: Even in MySQL, this isn't entirely equivalent to the original query, because rows with NULLs won't be counted.

Answer (score 11):

I have used this approach and it has worked for me.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DocumentID || DocumentSessionId) 
FROM  DocumentOutputItems
```

For my case, it provides correct result.

Comment: It does not give you the count of distinct values in conjunction of two columns. At least not in MySQL 5.8.

Comment: This question is tagged SQL Server, and this isn't SQL Server syntax

Comment: @AnwarShaikh I don't understand your comment. Do you mean to say it does not give you the count of distinct rows in the two columns "DocumentID" and "DocumentSessionID"?

Comment: Warning! This can get incorrect results. Consider DocumentID=123 with DocumentSessionId=21 and DocumentID=12 with DocumentSessionId=321

Answer (score 5):

If you're working with datatypes of fixed length, you can cast to `binary` to do this very easily and very quickly. Assuming `DocumentId` and `DocumentSessionId` are both `int`s, and are therefore 4 bytes long...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(DocumentId as binary(4)) + CAST(DocumentSessionId as binary(4)))
FROM DocumentOutputItems
```

My specific problem required me to divide a `SUM` by the `COUNT` of the distinct combination of various foreign keys and a date field, grouping by another foreign key and occasionally filtering by certain values or keys. The table is very large, and using a sub-query dramatically increased the query time. And due to the complexity, statistics simply wasn't a viable option. The `CHECKSUM` solution was also far too slow in its conversion, particularly as a result of the various data types, and I couldn't risk its unreliability.

However, using the above solution had virtually no increase on the query time (comparing with using simply the `SUM`), and should be completely reliable! It should be able to help others in a similar situation so I'm posting it here.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with your query, but you could also do it this way:

```
WITH internalQuery (Amount)
AS
(
    SELECT (0)
      FROM DocumentOutputItems
  GROUP BY DocumentId, DocumentSessionId
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDistinctRows
  FROM internalQuery
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this,

```
Select DocumentId, DocumentSessionId, count(*) as c 
from DocumentOutputItems 
group by DocumentId, DocumentSessionId;
```

This will get us the count of all possible combinations of DocumentId, and DocumentSessionId

Answer (score 3):

if you had only one field to "DISTINCT", you could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DocumentId) 
FROM DocumentOutputItems
```

and that does return the same query plan as the original, as tested with SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON.  However you are using two fields so you could try something crazy like:

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT convert(varchar(15),DocumentId)+'|~|'+convert(varchar(15), DocumentSessionId)) 
    FROM DocumentOutputItems
```

but you'll have issues if NULLs are involved.  I'd just stick with the original query.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this works i am writing on prima vista

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM DocumentOutputItems 
GROUP BY DocumentId, DocumentSessionId
```

Comment: In order for this to give the final answer, you would have to wrap it in another SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( ... ).  Essentially this answer is just giving you another way to list the distinct values you want to count.  It's no better than your original solution.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I know you can use group by instead of distinct in my case. I was wondering if you get the final result using just one query. I think is impossible but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I wish MS SQL could also do something like COUNT(DISTINCT A, B). But it can't.

At first JayTee's answer seemed like a solution to me bu after some tests CHECKSUM() failed to create unique values. A quick example is, both CHECKSUM(31,467,519) and CHECKSUM(69,1120,823) gives the same answer which is 55.

Then I made some research and found that Microsoft does NOT recommend using CHECKSUM for change detection purposes. In some forums some suggested using

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CHECKSUM(value1, value2, ..., valueN) + CHECKSUM(valueN, value(N-1), ..., value1))
```

but this is also not conforting.

You can use HASHBYTES() function as suggested in [TSQL CHECKSUM conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841331/tsql-checksum-conundrum). However this also has a small chance of not returning unique results.

I would suggest using

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(DocumentId AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(DocumentSessionId AS VARCHAR)) FROM DocumentOutputItems
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this when I Googled for my own issue, found that if you count DISTINCT objects, you get the correct number returned (I'm using MySQL)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DocumentID) AS Count1, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT DocumentSessionId) AS Count2
  FROM DocumentOutputItems
```

Comment: The above query will return a different set of results than what the OP was looking for (the distinct **combinations** of `DocumentId` and
`DocumentSessionId`). Alexander Kjäll already posted the correct answer if the OP was using MySQL and not MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. In oracle:

```
SELECT SUM(DECODE(COUNT(*),1,1,1))
FROM DocumentOutputItems GROUP BY DocumentId, DocumentSessionId;
```

In jpql:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(i)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 1 END)
FROM DocumentOutputItems i GROUP BY i.DocumentId, i.DocumentSessionId;
```

Comment: This question is not about Oracle. It's about SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question but the query I had was a sub-query with the comparison data in the main query. something like:

```
Select code, id, title, name 
(select count(distinct col1) from mytable where code = a.code and length(title) >0)
from mytable a
group by code, id, title, name
--needs distinct over col2 as well as col1
```

ignoring the complexities of this, I realized I couldn't get the value of a.code into the subquery with the double sub query described in the original question

```
Select count(1) from (select distinct col1, col2 from mytable where code = a.code...)
--this doesn't work because the sub-query doesn't know what "a" is
```

So eventually I figured out I could cheat, and combine the columns:

```
Select count(distinct(col1 || col2)) from mytable where code = a.code...
```

This is what ended up working

Comment: What does 1 mean in count(1)?

Comment: @devloper152: It has no special meaning. For some reason `count()` always has to have an argument, so depending on people's taste they'll typically use `count(*)`, `count(1)`, or `count(null)`.

Comment: To be clear, `||` is a concatenation operator in some databases. This question is about SQL Server, where `+` would be the equivalent. Just like all the other answers on this question recommending concatenation, this suffers from the problem that combinations of different values ('a', 'bc' vs 'ab', 'c') can concatenate to the same value ('abc'), giving you an incorrect count.

Answer (score 0):

This query helps me (in MSSQL) find the unique count with more than one column.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT concat_column) AS unique_count
FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(column1, '|', column2, '|', column3) AS concat_column
  FROM your_table_name_here
) AS subquery;
```

Answer (score -1):

This code uses distinct on 2 parameters and provides count of number of rows specific to those distinct values row count. It worked for me in MySQL like a charm.

```
select DISTINCT DocumentId as i,  DocumentSessionId as s , count(*) 
from DocumentOutputItems   
group by i ,s;
```

Answer (score -6):

You can just use the Count Function Twice.

In this case, it would be:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT DocumentId), COUNT (DISTINCT DocumentSessionId) 
FROM DocumentOutputItems
```

Comment: this doesn't do as require in the question, it counts the distinct in separate for each column