# count with where clause multiple condition on same table

Tags: sql, join, count, subquery, where-clause

I have a table called products.

```
ProductId| ProductName| ProductType| ProductSize
1        | a          | yellow     |  12
2        | b          | green      |  13
3        | c          | yellow     |  12
4        | d          | yellow     |  15
________________________________________________
```

I want to get count of each product as a column at end, where productType, and ProductSize match, the excepted result I want to be..

```
ProductID|ProductName|ProductType|ProductSize|TotalProduct
1        | a         | yellow    | 12        | 2
2        | b         | green     | 13        | 1
3        | c         | yellow    | 12        | 2
4        | d         | yellow    | 15        | 1
_________________________________________________________
```

### some what I have try, but failed is look like this.

```
select ProductId, ProductName, ProductType, ProductSize,
(select count(*) from Product where ProductType=(Products.ProductType) and ProductSize=(products.productSize)) as [TotalProduct] from Products
```

---

its return totalProduct = 4 for all the record.
thanks

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664043/how-can-i-count-distinct-multiple-fields-without-repeating-the-query

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most versions of SQL, you would use window/analytic functions:

```
select ProductId, ProductName, ProductType, ProductSize,
       count(*) over (partition by producttype, productsize)
from products p
```

The problem with your query is that you are not giving the table names aliases.  So an expression like `ProductSize=(products.productSize)` is not correlated with the outer query.  It is actually equivalent to `ProductSize = ProductSize` on the inner query.  You could fix that by just putting `from Products p` in the inner query.  However, the window function approach is better in databases that support it (most of them).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result by using a subquery to get the count for each `producttype` and `productsize` that match:

```
select producttype, productsize, count(*) TotalProduct
from product
group by producttype, productsize;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1175c/4).

Then you can join your `product` table to this subquery to get the final result:

```
select p1.productid,
  p1.productname,
  p1.producttype,
  p1.productsize,
  p2.totalProduct
from product p1
inner join
(
  select producttype, productsize, count(*) TotalProduct
  from product
  group by producttype, productsize
) p2
  on p1.producttype = p2.producttype
  and p1.productsize = p2.productsize;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1175c/3). This gives a result:

```
| PRODUCTID | PRODUCTNAME | PRODUCTTYPE | PRODUCTSIZE | TOTALPRODUCT |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |           a |      yellow |          12 |            2 |
|         2 |           b |       green |          13 |            1 |
|         3 |           c |      yellow |          12 |            2 |
|         4 |           d |      yellow |          15 |            1
```