# COUNT(DISTINCT) in multiple columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

In Oracle, it's possible to get a count of distinct values in multiple columns by using the **||** operator (according to [this forum post](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?t=11349), anyway):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnA || ColumnB) FROM MyTable
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server 2008?  I'm trying to perform a single query to return some group statistics, but I can't seem to do it.

For example, here is a table of values I'm trying to query:

```
AssetId MyId    TheirId   InStock
328     10      10        1
328     20      20        0
328     30      30        0
328     40      10        0
328     10      10        0
328     10      10        0
328     10      10        0
328     10      10        0
```

For AssetId #328, I want to compute the total number of unique IDs in the **MyId** and **TheirId** columns (4 = 10, 20, 30, 40), as well as the total number of non-zero rows in the **InStock** column (1):

```
AssetId     TotalIds    AvailableIds
328         4           1
```

Is there a way to work this magic somehow?

Comment: This question on SO may help: [counting distinct over multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471250/counting-distinct-over-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `cross apply` and `values`.

```
select T1.AssetId,
       count(distinct T2.ID) TotalIds,
       sum(case T2.InStock when 0 then 0 else 1 end) AvailableIds 
from YourTable as T1
  cross apply(values(T1.MyId, T1.InStock),
                    (T1.TheirId, 0)
             ) as T2(ID, InStock)
group by T1.AssetId
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77189)

Or you can do a `union all` in a sub query.

```
select T.AssetId,
       count(distinct T.ID) TotalIds,
       sum(case T.InStock when 0 then 0 else 1 end) AvailableIds 
from (
     select AssetId, MyId as ID, InStock
     from YourTable
     union all
     select AssetID, TheirId, 0
     from YourTable
     ) as T
group by T.AssetId
```

Comment: Wow. +1 on coolness but the cross apply could be a performance killer.

Comment: @Lieven It does not look so on the execution plan. It will only do one table scan and the cross apply does a constant scan. But the solutions provided should of course be tested with a realistic amount of data. It might be a different story with a lot of rows.

Comment: Sorry for the redonk delay in marking your answer as accepted, and thank you for the workable solution.  I was hoping for an elegant native solution, but in the absence of that I'll settle for a working one... cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the Oracle example and concatenate the values together (that is what the Oracle query is doing).  You just have to convert the values to characters first:

```
select AssetId,
       count(distinct cast(MyId as varchar(8000))+','+cast(TheirId as varchar(8000)
            ) totalIds,
       count(distinct case when inStock> 0
                           then cast(MyId as varchar(8000))+','+cast(TheirId as varchar(8000)
             end) as AvailableIds
from t
group by Assetid
```

You can also do it as a subquery:

```
select AssetId, count(*) as TotalIds,
       sum(case when inStock > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as AvailableIds
from (select AssetId, myId, theirId, max(inStock) as inStock
      from t
      group by AssetId, myId, theirId
     ) a
group by AssetId
```

"Theoretically", I like the second approach better, since it is more set-based.  However, if you find yourself trying to count distinct combinations columns in several different variables, the string concatenation approach is more practical.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (AssetId INT, MyId    INT, TheirId   INT, InStock INT)
INSERT @t
VALUES 
(328,10, 10,   1)
,(328,20, 20,   0)
,(328,30, 30,   0)
,(328,40, 10,   0)
,(328,10, 10,   0)
,(328,10, 10,   0)
,(328,10, 10,   0)
,(328,10, 10,   0)

;WITH a AS(
    SELECT  AssetId,
            COUNT(col) cnt
    FROM 
    (
            SELECT  MyId col, AssetId
            FROM    @t
            UNION
            SELECT  TheirId col, AssetId
            FROM    @t
    ) b
    GROUP BY AssetId
)

SELECT  a.AssetId,
        a.cnt TotalIds,
        SUM(CASE WHEN InStock <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AvailableIds
FROM    @t c
JOIN    a ON a.AssetId = c.AssetId
GROUP   BY a.AssetId, a.cnt
```

In Common Table Expression (`WITH` code block) 'uniqueness' is guaranteed by using `UNION` operator which discards duplicate values, that's why `COUNT(col)` doesn't need to be used like `COUNT(DISTINCT col)`.

Comment: Very similar to answer I was going to post! +1

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using CTEs, since it kills the performance of my query, increasing it by over 100% when processing large datasets.  This is the solution I already have, but I was hoping there was some clever way of doing it, like with Oracle's "||" operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's good solution for you

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2 
      FROM MyTable) A
```

Comment: This does not show groups, just a single count.  Not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1

```
select 
          AssetID, count(distinct MyId) As MyId, SUM(InStock) InStock
From T
Group By 
      AssetID
```

### Option #2 Without CTE

```
Select AssetID, count(MyId), sum(InStock) InStock From
(
    select 
            AssetID, MyId, SUM(InStock) InStock
    From MyTable
    Group By 
            AssetID, MyId
)K
Group by AssetID
```

### Option #3 With CTE

```
;With Sub(AssetID, MyId, InStock)
As
(
    select 
            AssetID, MyId, SUM(InStock) InStock
    From MyTable
    Group By 
            AssetID, MyId
)

Select AssetID, count(MyId), sum(InStock) From
(
    Select * from Sub
)K
```

Comment: The column `theirID` is also required.

Comment: @Lieven - I think `TheirID` is not required Please check the sample output shared in the Query.

Comment: Per OP *I want to compute the total number of unique IDs in the MyId and TheirId columns* I'm pretty sure that `theirID` *is* required.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to use `CTE's`, you can try using following solution. The gist of it is to

- select the `TotalID's` for each `AssetID` in a seperate subquery
- select the `AvailableIDs` for each `AssetID` in a seperate subquery
- `JOIN` the results of both subqueries to produce the final results.

The statement as is works on the entire table. You can get the results for a single AssetID by adding an appropriate where clause to the entire group.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  a.AssetId, t.TotalIDs, a.AvailableIDs
FROM    (
            SELECT  AssetID, TotalIDs = COUNT(*) 
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  AssetID 
                        FROM    MyTable 
                        GROUP BY 
                                MyId, TheirID, AssetID
                    ) t 
            GROUP BY 
                    AssetID
        ) AS t
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  AssetID, AvailableIDs = SUM(InStock) 
            FROM    MyTable 
            GROUP BY 
                    AssetID
        ) AS a ON a.AssetId = t.AssetId
```

**Test script**

```
;WITH MyTable (AssetId, MyId, TheirId, InStock) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        (328, 10, 10, 1)
        , (328, 20, 20, 0)
        , (328, 30, 30, 0)
        , (328, 40, 10, 0)
        , (328, 10, 10, 0)
        , (328, 10, 10, 0)
        , (328, 10, 10, 0)
        , (328, 10, 10, 0)
        , (329, 10, 10, 0)
        , (329, 10, 20, 1)
    ) AS a (b, c, d, e)
)
SELECT  a.AssetId, t.TotalIDs, a.AvailableIDs
FROM    (
            SELECT  AssetID, TotalIDs = COUNT(*) 
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  AssetID 
                        FROM    MyTable 
                        GROUP BY 
                                MyId, TheirID, AssetID
                    ) t 
            GROUP BY 
                    AssetID
        ) AS t
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  AssetID, AvailableIDs = SUM(InStock) 
            FROM    MyTable 
            GROUP BY 
                    AssetID
        ) AS a ON a.AssetId = t.AssetId
```