# Is there a way to improve performance of this query (aggregation)

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

Here is the query:

```
SELECT  sdd.CompanyID 
            ,sdd.ClassID 
            ,sdd.PeriodID, SUM(sdd.Volume) AS VolumeTotal, SUM(sdd.Dollars) AS DollasTotal
            ,COUNT(LogID) as LogIDCount

    FROM (SELECT dp.CompanyID 
                ,ds.ClassID 
                ,fs.PeriodID, fs.LogID, sum(fs.Volume) AS Volume,sum(fs.Dollars) AS Dollars
    FROM DW.FactSupplyDataDetail fs     WITH (NOLOCK)
        JOIN DW.DimPLProvider dp    WITH (NOLOCK) 
            ON fs.PLProviderID = dp.PLProviderID
        JOIN DW.DimSupply ds    WITH (NOLOCK) 
            ON fs.SupplyID = ds.SupplyID
        WHERE fs.PeriodID between 201901 and 201907
        GROUP BY dp.CompanyID 
                ,ds.ClassID 
                ,fs.PeriodID,fs.LogID) sdd
    GROUP BY sdd.CompanyID 
            ,sdd.ClassID 
            ,sdd.PeriodID
```

here is the execution plan for the query:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkoxSEjEH

```
DW.FactSupplyDataDetail has 10590237 records
DW.DimPLProvider has 5071 records
DW.DimSupply has 81001 records

result of a query is 1992094
```

Comment: Could you use [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for us?

Comment: You could get rid of the useless `SUM()` columns.

Comment: And careful with [adding NOLOCK](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) everywhere... it has some terrible side affects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920317/countdistinct-in-multiple-columns-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @scsimon there is a link to Execution plan screenshot.

Comment: @TabAlleman you suggesting to use count(distinct LogID), I tried, it runs super slow...

Comment: ```You could get rid of the useless SUM() columns.``` @TabAlleman, i need them, it's actually  just a sub query, I use sum() columns in an outer query

Comment: By showing us only part of the query, you obfuscated the question.  If you are doing more than just getting a single COUNT() then my comments don't apply.

Comment: I see the link, but we need the XML...Read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) as well as [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) for why. Also, using paste the plan allows us to see inside the XML on attributes that you can not capture with an image.

Comment: @scsimon posted real query that I'm trying to improve, and also posted a query plan. Thank you.

Comment: @TabAlleman posted real query that I'm trying to improve, and also posted a query plan. Thank you.

Comment: Looking at that index seek, I would suggest you [update your statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @scsimon UPDATE STATISTICS on all the tables didn't help

Comment: What would happen if you just pre-aggregated on the items in the Fact table, then used _that_ to join out to your other tables and get your counts and a count(distinct LogID) at that point? That would likely result in a join on a smaller set of data for the Company and Class values.

Answer (score 0):

Check that

1. Table FactSupplyDataDetail has index started from PeriodID
2. Table DimSupply has index started from SupplyID
3. Table DimPLProvider has index started from PLProviderID

The table TABLE has index started from column COLUMN means that you have index (idx_xxx_) defined as:

CREATE INDEX idx_xxx on TABLE (COLUMN, some other columns or empty list);

Comment: FactSupplyDataDetail Table has an index staring with PeriodID.  SupplyID is a PK in DimSupply table, and  PLProviderID is a PK in DimPLProvider so there is a clustered index with *ID column on both.