# How to select distinct on specific columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, distinct

I have few columns in a table

**Col1**, **Col2**, **Col3**, **Col4**

Now I want to select like this

`SELECT DISTINCT (Col1, Col2, Col3), Col4`

i.e. get the distinct based on only these three colunms.

Comment: What about the `Col4` you need to perform some aggregation on this for each distinct value of the other 3 columns?

Comment: You may get help from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471250/counting-distinct-over-multiple-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a comment to another answer:

> Can I get like this Col1, Col2 , Col3 and (Col4 in delimiter form)

Yes, you can use the `for xml path`.

```
select Col1, 
       Col2,  
       Col3, 
       (
        select ',' + T2.Col4
        from YourTable T2
        where T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 and
              T1.Col2 = T2.Col2 and
              T1.Col3 = T2.Col3
        for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring((./text())[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as Col4
from YourTable as T1
group by T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T1.Col3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40b2a/1/0)

Answer (score 8):

Just `GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3` with an aggregate function with the `col4` like `MAX`, `MIN`, etc .. like so:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, MAX(Col4)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
```

Comment: That is a varchar field , I just want to have distinct records based on three columns.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite What about `col4` what do you want to do for it for each distinct value for the other rows?

Comment: Col4 is varchar and i can't do any aggregation on that. but that is unique column. I wanted to get unique of 3 columns and just add the fourth column related to that row

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite  Can you please show me some sample data and how it should look like after that query?

Comment: Can I get like this Col1, Col2 , Col3 and (Col4 in delimiter form)

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite Do you mean concatenate values for `col4` into one column? if so, then you can, but there is no built in function to do this in sql server. You have to do this manual using a stored procedure or a user defined function, and if you searched the internet you will find a lot of implementations for such a function.

Answer (score 1):

The group by and distinct perform almost similar functionality in SQL:

SO both queries below are almost equivalent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM tbl

SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM tbl GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
```

Comment: But I want to have Col4 also in the resultset

Comment: Why dont you write an inner query doing distinct of 3 columns and the outer query taking inner 3 and Col4 of matching rows ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct ( Convert(varchar(255),Col1) +' '+
Convert(varchar(255),Col2)+' '+Convert(varchar(255),Col3)),
Col4 from clients
```