# Counts rows returned by query that uses distinct

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, distinct

I have a simple query in this form:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c
FROM MyTable
WHERE a = SomeConditionsEtc
```

etc...

But I need to know how many rows it's going to return. Initially I was doing this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a)
FROM MyTable
WHERE a = SomeConditionsEtc
```

But that's not reliable in case `a` contains duplicates where the other don't. So now I'm using a nested query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE a = SomeConditionsEtc) AS Temp
```

Is that the correct approach or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you looked at the following SO post already?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471250/counting-distinct-over-multiple-columns

Comment: @Sam No I haven't seen that yet, thanks. Well I guess the nested query is the simplest solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is straight to the point, does the job, and it's simple enough, I'm sure you can bake some unnecessary rocket science into it, but would be overblown imho.  Aside from what you have, you can use a `group by` like below to illustrate what I mean, but you will be basically doing the same thing, getting the uniques and counting them.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (SELECT a
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE a = 'a'
        GROUP BY a, b, c) Temp
```