# SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT... ) error on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, VehicleModelYear, containing columns id, year, make, and model.

The following two queries work as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT make, model
FROM VehicleModelYear

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT make)
FROM VehicleModelYear
```

However, this query doesn't work

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT make, model)
FROM VehicleModelYear
```

It's clear the answer is the number of results returned by the first query, but just wondering what is wrong with this syntax or why it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting DISTINCT over multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471250/counting-distinct-over-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`COUNT()` in `SQL Server` accepts the following syntax

```
COUNT(*)
COUNT(colName)
COUNT(DISTINCT colName)
```

You can have a subquery which returns unique set of `make` and `model` that you can count with.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT make, model
            FROM    VehicleModelYear
        ) a
```

The "a" at the end is not a typo. It's an alias without which SQL will give an error `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias`.

Answer (score 19):

Try combining them into a single field:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT make + ' ' + model)
FROM VehicleModelYear
```

Comment: or `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CHECKSUM(make, model)) 
FROM VehicleModelYear`

Comment: When I can find a scalar expression that maps back to columns, when the columns are strings or easily castable, and when there are few columns in the expression, I use this. It's quick and dirty.

Comment: If not referring to columns which are strings, for example int columns - this answer doesn't result in the correct value but won't generate an error when being executed. As @Ian Elder's comment states,the columns could be casted in order to get this to work correctly. Anyone have some info on why this doesn't fail (for int columns) and what's going on?

Comment: Checksum is better as you do not have to worry about casting.

Comment: Be sure to run a performance comparison of the checksum solution vs just wrapping the multi column distinct into another sub query and doing a count on that.

Answer (score 7):

The syntax is valid SQL but has not been implemented in SQL-Server.

Try a rewrite:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT DISTINCT make, model
    FROM VehicleModelYear
  )
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM cte ;
```

or:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT model) AS cnt
    FROM VehicleModelYear
    GROUP BY make
  )
SELECT SUM(cnt) AS total
FROM cte ;
```

or:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT NULL AS n
    FROM VehicleModelYear
    GROUP BY make, model
  )
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM cte ;
```

And finally, the 2nd and 3rd query above modified, without subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT model)) OVER () AS total
FROM VehicleModelYear
GROUP BY make ;

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () AS total
FROM VehicleModelYear
GROUP BY make, model ;
```

---

Late additions by [@Alexander Fedorenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085940/alexander-fedorenko):

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT model)) OVER () AS total
FROM VehicleModelYear
GROUP BY make ;

SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(*) OVER () AS total
FROM VehicleModelYear
GROUP BY make, model ;
```

or:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY make, model) AS dr
    FROM VehicleModelYear
  )
SELECT MAX(dr) AS total
FROM cte ;
```