# MySQL - combine record counts having same column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count the number of records in my query with the same EventDate. Here is my query:

```
SELECT EventName, EventDate
FROM Schedule s
JOIN Groups g
ON s.GroupID = g.GroupID
JOIN Organizations o
ON g.OrganizationID = o.OrganizationID
WHERE o.OrganizationID = 2
AND s.CreateDate > o.EvalEndDate
ORDER BY ID
```

And here is the first chunk of the result set:

[image]

I need to know how many records in this list have the same exact EventDate. If I use GROUP BY, I do get the correct number of rows -- but I don't need to see all the rows; I only need the count. A single number. How do I do this? For this query, it so happens that there are exactly 2 records for each datetime. The raw query produces 108 records, which means the count I am looking for is exactly half that: 54. I need a query that gives me that count.

IMPORTANT: I cannot just do a count(*) and divide that by 2, because there is no guarantee there will always be 2 records for each date. It will be a common occurrence, but there will be variances.

Comment: I think that's what the DISTINCT keyword is for. Try COUNT(DISTINCT EventDate).

Comment: Do you want to see the number of DISTINCT EventDates?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968963/select-countdistinct-error-on-multiple-columns This will work if you need distinct combinations of eventname and eventdate.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT EventDate) nailed it! gandaliter, do you want to post that answer?