# Aggregation query: group and count by multiple number of dynamically selected columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I have the following table `logs`:

```
session_id | event_type   | event_value
-----------+--------------+------------
   505     | user_profile | /admin
   505     | page_viewed  | /profile/18
   506     | user_profile | /member
   506     | page_viewed  | /home
   507     | user_profile | /admin
   507     | page_viewed  | /profile/18
   508     | user_profile | /member
   508     | page_viewed  | /profile/18
```

I would like to group by all possible values in event_type (user_profile and page_viewed), and count each possible combinaison.

The result should look like this:

```
user_profile | page_viewed | count
-------------+-------------+------
   admin     | /profile/18 |  2    # session_ids 505 and 507
   member    | /home       |  1    # session_ids 506
   member    | /profile/18 |  1    # session_ids 508
```

Note that the couple `user_profile, page_viewed` may change. It may be, for example, `user_profile, user_gender, session_duration`.

Counting/grouping over multiple columns could be done [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471250/counting-distinct-over-multiple-columns), but I have no idea how to select rows dynamically...

Is it possible to do such a query with postgresql ?

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ded1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_profile, page_viewed, 
       count(*) as cnt,
       '# session_ids ' ||
       STRING_AGG(session_id, ' and ' order by session_id) as sess
from (
  select max(case when event_type = 'user_profile' 
              then event_value else null end) as user_profile,
         max(case when event_type = 'page_viewed' 
              then event_value else null end) as page_viewed,
         session_id
  from logs
  group by session_id
) sub group by user_profile, page_viewed;
```

Some info about STRING_AGG here:
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/191-String-Aggregation-in-PostgreSQL,-SQL-Server,-and-MySQL.html

Comment: The comment `session_ids 505 and 507` was just to be explicit about what aggregation I want, I don't really want to select it. So the STRING_AGG is not really needed here. I would love to have a solution where `user_profile` and `page_viewed` is dynamic (not specified in the query). But I can do a first query to list the columns I need, and then generate this query based on what the columns are. So this is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean some thing like this:(this is executed in Ms Sql Server and you may be need to change it to Postgresql)

```
DECLARE @selectColumns AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @selectColumns='user_profile,page_viewed'

EXEC('SELECT '+@selectColumns+',COUNT(*) FROM tbltest GROUP BY event_type,'+ @selectColumns)
```