# MYSQL Count unique values for each row

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database structure and values:

```
name  | x | y | z
------------------
name1 | 1 | 1 | 2
name2 | 2 | 1 | 3 
name3 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

And now i need add extra column with counter unique values (x,y,z) for each row:

```
name  | x | y | z | unique
--------------------------
name1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2
name2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3
name3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use select count distinct

```
SELECT *,COUNT (DISTINCT column-name)  FROM table-name;
```

more answers here > [Counting DISTINCT over multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471250/counting-distinct-over-multiple-columns), its already been answered.

Comment: did this answer  help?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it to scale massively you can do this

```
SELECT *, 
(CASE 
 WHEN x=y=z THEN 1
 WHEN x=y OR x=z OR y=z THEN 2
 ELSE 3
END) as `unique`
FROM `table`
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have more columns and several millions of rows. Any other idea?

Comment: @kuguary are you using this in conjunction with php or just direct sql queries?