# Count distinct over multiple columns in USQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'd like to count distinct over two columns.

In imaginary sql, I'd write the below:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT col1, col2)
```

In T-SQL, this is done by having one grouping in a sub query and then a second grouping in the outer query - [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471250/counting-distinct-over-multiple-columns)

As far as I know, USQL doesn't have sub queries, so I'm a bit stuck trying to work out how to do this. I suppose I could use two aliased queries, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U-SQL does support subqueries. What it does not (yet) support are *scalar* subqueries and *correlated* subqueries (use a join for both instead).

So the solution

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DocumentId, DocumentSessionId
      FROM DocumentOutputItems) AS internalQuery
```

or the mentioned `SUM(CASE)` with `GROUP BY` in the link above both work.

Alternatively, U-SQL also allows you to name the inner query and use it in the outer statement which makes the script easier to read for more complex cases (it is similar to a common-table expression in that it does only name the query and does not execute it):

```
@inner = 
  SELECT DISTINCT DocumentId, DocumentSessionId
  FROM DocumentOutputItems;
@result = SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM @inner;
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen any examples of sub queries in the documentation, so assumed they weren't possible. As you say, the aliased queries are normally much more readable, but I've got a process that's generating usql, to emulate CUBE functionality, so subqueires fit my process better

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use subquery then one "ugly" way is to concatenate columns:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT String.Concat(col1, '^', col2))
FROM tab;
```

Of course you have to handle NULLs and convert to proper data type.