# Count distinct elements across multiple columns

Tags: count, distinct

I have a scenario where I got multiple columns with similar content. I want to count how many distinct values are there in all the columns. Slightly different to the below linked case where content of two columns are looked at as a single attribute/element.

[Counting DISTINCT over multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471250/counting-distinct-over-multiple-columns)

[image: StudentClubs]

My table is as above. I need to go thru all club columns and count how many distinct clubs there are.

The below code I managed only counts distinct rows. Not individual distinct elements in each column.

```
select count(*) from( select distinct Club1 Club2 from StudentClubs) as ClubCount
```

The above returns 6

I need it to output 12 as there are 12 clubs in total.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the below solution as a interim. First stacking the columns and then using a count distinct.
It seem to work at least in this example.

```
select count(distinct A.Club1)
from (

select Club1 from StudentClubs as A
union all
select Club2 from StudentClubs as A
union all
select Club3 from StudentClubs as A
union all 
select Club4 from StudentClubs as A
) as A
```

The above outputs 12.
Please do share if you have better ways to handle this.
Thanks