# postgresql while/loop function

Tags: postgresql, loops

is there a way to replace/simplified the following code with while/loop function? I need to loop it while items < specific number or variable. Thank you!

```
select 
count(distinct wallet) filter (where items >= 3 and items < 6) + 
count(distinct wallet) filter (where items >= 6 and items < 9) + 
count(distinct wallet) filter (where items >= 9 and items < 12) +
count(distinct wallet) filter (where items >= 12 and items < 15) as total_items

from 
agg
where items > 0
```

Comment: Doesn't this just simplify to `select count(distinct wallet) filter (where items >= 3 and items < 15) as total_items`?

Comment: I have to go by increments of 3.

Comment: Oh, right, you need the `distinct` per group, which would sum to a different count than counting all wallets that fall anywhere in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to loop this. (Well, there is, but it's overcomplicated and probably inefficient).

You can however just use maths to reduce the `items` to one canonical element per group, and then [count the distinct tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1471250/1048572) consisting of the `wallet` and the respective canonical element:

```
select count(distinct (wallet, items/3)) as total_items
from agg
where items >= 3 and items < 15
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked exactly as I need!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function for this as below:

```
create or replace function dist_items(threshold integer, init_val integer, val_diff integer) returns integer as $$
        DECLARE
            start_pos integer;
            end_pos integer;
            terminator integer;
            temp integer default 0;
            res integer default 0;
        BEGIN
                IF init_val > threshold
                THEN
                    RETURN 0;
                END IF;
                terminator:= 0;
                start_pos:= init_val;
                end_pos := start_pos + val_diff;
                LOOP
                EXIT WHEN terminator = 1;                
                    SELECT count(distinct wallet) filter (where items >= start_pos and items < end_pos) into temp from agg where items > 0;
                    res := res + temp;
                    start_pos := start_pos + val_diff;
                    end_pos := start_pos + val_diff;
                    IF (start_pos >= threshold)
                    THEN
                        terminator:= 1;
                    END IF;
                    IF (end_pos > threshold)
                    THEN
                        end_pos:= threshold;
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
                RETURN res;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```