# PostgreSQL arrange calculated columns horizontaly

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of real state properties and I want to create a table that shows me the count of the properties that fall in certain price range by zones, something like this:

```
Zone     0-149k    150-300k
North       25         150
South      150         350
```

For example for the first result my query would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY TABLE
WHERE ZONE = 'North' AND PRICE < 150000
```

and similar for the other fields

But I'm unable to find a unified query that shows me the data in the desired way. I've tried with the `UNION` command but this shows me all the data as continuous rows. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`FILTER` on an aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT
  zone,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE price < 150000) AS "0-149k",
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE 150000 <= price AND price < 300000) AS "150-300k"
FROM my_table
GROUP BY zone;
```

(If you have an unknown number of price ranges, see [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68748542/1048572)).